# Contactform.php not sending all inputs

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a contact form that is working fine, it sends the email except that it **doesn't post the email address** of the person that sends it. I have no idea why, I tried changing the $from variable and nothing changes. Is there something obvious I am missing?

It is the input with the id **c_email** which is put into the **$from** variable that I do not receive in the emails sent by this form.

My contactform.php:

```
<?php

// Contact
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Portfolio ContactForm';

if(isset($_POST['c_name']) && isset($_POST['c_email']) && isset($_POST['c_message'])){
$name    = $_POST['c_name'];
    $from   = $_POST['c_email'];
    $message = $_POST['c_message'];

    if (mail($to, $subject, $from, $name, $message)) { 
        $result = array(
            'message' => 'Sent, thanks!',
            'sendstatus' => 1
            );
        echo json_encode($result);
    } else { 
        $result = array(
            'message' => 'Ooops, problem..',
            'sendstatus' => 1
            );
        echo json_encode($result);
    } 
}?>
```

On my html page:

```
<form id="contact-form" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="c_name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="c_name" class="form-control" name="c_name" placeholder="Nom">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="c_email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="c_email" class="form-control" name="c_email" placeholder="E-mail">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="c_message" name="c_message" rows="7" placeholder="Votre message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-1">
                <i class="fa fa-bullhorn icon-before"></i> Envoyer
        </button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values is not posting because in your form you not mention **method="POST"**.Just try like this.it should work

```
<form id="contact-form" role="form" action="" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="c_name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="c_name" class="form-control" name="c_name" placeholder="Nom">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="c_email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="c_email" class="form-control" name="c_email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="c_message" name="c_message" rows="7" placeholder="Votre message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-1">
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn icon-before"></i> Envoyer
    </button>

</form>
<script>
$('button').click(function() {
var c_name = $("#c_name").val();
var c_email = $("#c_email").val();
var c_message = $("#c_message").val();
$.ajax({//create an ajax request to load_page.php
type: "POST",
url: "assets/php/contactForm.php",
data:{"c_name":c_name,"c_email":c_email,"c_message":c_message},
success: function(data) {
    if (data) {

       alert(data);
    }
    else {
        alert('Successfully not posted.');
    }
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a custom .js file with the post message in it:

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "assets/php/contactForm.php",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
      c_email: c_email,
      c_name: c_name,
      c_message: c_message (...)
So the post method isn't the problem. I am receiving the information, the form works, but only the "email input" is not showing in the emails I receive.